# Is there any time limit in the List view of the iPhone Calendar app?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

Is there any time limit in the List view of the iPhone Calendar app, beyond which we cannot make any entries? Can this limit be changed to something else than the 2 years set by by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit in the Calendar itself – you can 'zoom out' by repeatedly tapping the Back button until you're in a screen where each year takes up about a single page. Scroll down to e.g. 2027, and you can create an event in the distant future without problems:

[image]

The List view *does* seem to have a built-in limit of two years, which can't be extended by settings.

Comment: Thanks for response,,but latest two years entries only showing in agenda list and not beyond that...Is there a way to see more than 2 years entries in agenda list..Like 2027 entry you created..

Comment: Ah, you mean the List view. There seems to be no option to extend that period beyond two years.

Comment: Yes List view and there is no way to view beyond 2 years.....No idea why this limitation they have put on list view....

Comment: In Google and blackberry phone there seems to be no such  limit..Why is it so with apple phone..Really frustrating it is...

Answer (score 0):

To add to the same "List view not displaying beyond 2 years". Calendar allowed me to enter an event beyond 2 years, but it will not find it if I search. The search takes me to the last week of 2 years.

I've switched to ToDo Pro for "far out" tasks.

Tony